# Django - skip first row of array

Tags: django, arrays, django-templates

I have a fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find a simple solution to it.
I'd like to iterate through an array in my Django template but skip the first value.

Let's say I have an array like this that I pass to my template through a view:

```
array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

In my template I do :

{% for a in array %}
{{ a }}
{% endfor %}

How can I do to only print '2' '3' '4' '5', without the first value ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
{% for a in array|slice:"1:" %}{{ a }}{% endfor %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#slice for more information.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. I'll look into this slice function, I didn't know about it

Comment: Having trouble with this when the array is a Queryset. I think @Some programmer dude's answer works more universally.

Answer (score 9):

```
{% for a in array %}
  {% if not forloop.first %}
    {{ a }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

There is of course `forloop.last` for the last iteration as well.

They are all listed in the Django [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for).

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for a in array %}
{% if forloop.counter != 1 %}
    {{ a }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Jeremy Lewis's solution is probably cleaner unless you want to do something with the first value