# how to skip first element from from loop in django

Tags: python, django

this is my `home.html`

```
{% for i in ind %}
{{ i.state }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

in this for loop i do not want first data coming from ind, i want all data except first data then how to iterate this for loop, this is `Django project`

this is my `views.py`

```
res = requests.get("https://api.covid19india.org/data.json")
ind = res.json()['statewise']
```

the data of ind variable is going to for loop but i do not want first data of ind variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - skip first row of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993763/django-skip-first-row-of-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
{% for i in ind %}
    {% if not forloop.first %}  
        {{ i.state }}<br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`ind` will be looped through, but `{{ i.state }}` will be printed for the first element.

Or, as you can see from the comment section. It is the other way.

```
{% for i in ind|slice:"1:" %}
    {{ i.state }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) for counter concept ind django.